# Java - how to combine mp3 with jpg/png/

Tags: java, png, mp3, jpeg

I need to develop a functionality similar to iTunes where when you right-click a song → get artwork, the JPEG/PNG is "embedded" into the mp3 file.
I also need to embed the other ID3 details as well, so a library that could help me with all would be great.

I have no idea how this could be done, do you have any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) library seems to do what you are searching for (see [here](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_artwork.jsp)).

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully used [setPictureData(...)](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/javadoc/org/blinkenlights/jid3/v2/APICID3V2Frame.html#setPictureData(byte[])) of [JID3](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org) to add covers to my MP3 collection that did not have any images attached to them. Also have a look at their [sample page](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/samples.html) to see how the library can be used.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at id3 tags for the mp3s thats how you embed album art in an mp3.

See reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've worked out how to add the actual meta-data, how about using MusicBrainz to find them? I always find that's pretty good for finding music information. It's like the "Wikipedia of music".

http://musicbrainz.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract and persist the MP3 ID3 tag metadata including artwork to a database through hibernate with the help of an IdTag POJO, [here](http://code-stream.blogspot.in/2012/04/jaudiotagger-java-library-for-editing.html) is a simple example which uses the [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) Java library.